# Looking for a counting function for combinations of optional and non optional sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Per [How do I calculate the number of different combinations of multiple sets' elements (different number of elements on each set)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149800/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-different-combinations-of-multiple-sets-elemen), I'm able to count the number of possible combinations of multiple sets.

But what if some of those sets are optional meaning that they may be both include and exclude from the finally tally?  So per the example:

[apples, oranges, lemons]

[a, b, c, d, e]

[black, white, red, blue]

[1, 2]

if [black, white, red, blue] was optional, I would also need to count [apples, a, 1], [apples, a, 2], etc.  Even more, if both [black, white, red, blue] and [a,b,c,d,e] were optional, I would need to further take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each "optional" set, add another element. That is, if [black, white, red, blue] was optional, consider instead [black, white, red, blue, empty] and apply the original technique.

---

Edit:

Suppose you have your four sets stated above, with the colors optional and the letters optional. As I suggest, add an extra element to each optional class to get the following.

[apples, oranges, lemons]

[a, b, c, d, e, empty]

[black, white, red, blue, empty]

[1, 2]

I claim the answer is $3 \times 6 \times 5 \times 2$. Indeed, just consider constructing all "combinations" of one element from each set, while regarding "empty" elements as invisible.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct as the answer would be the rule of product for all sets + the rule of products for the non-optional sets.  However, this would work for one optional set but we would need to take multiple optional sets into account.

Comment: I see my mistake.  You are correct.  Thank you!